# CARGAR IMAGENES A LA BASE DE DATOS FIRESTORE DESDE IONIC 4

Tags: typescript, ionic4

tengo el crud funcionando conectada a la base de datos firestore haces las cuatro funciones del crud, pero entonces he capturado con la camara de mi móvil y tratar de subirle a firestore, convirtiendo la imagen en base 64 y que anteriormente a la base de datos firebase real time si lo cargaba sin problemas alguien me podria ayudar como hago para subir una imagen a firestore este es el código en service.ts

```
export class CrudService {

 constructor(
   private firestore: AngularFirestore
 ) { }

// crearemos nuestro nuevo documento
 create_report(record) {
   return this.firestore.collection('reportes').add(record);
 }
// leeremos nuestros documentos existentes
 read_report() {
   return this.firestore.collection('reportes').snapshotChanges();
 }
// actualizaremos nuestros documentos existentes
 update_report(recordID,record){
   this.firestore.doc('reportes/' + recordID).update(record);
 }
 // borraremos nuestros documentos

 delete_report(record_id) {
   this.firestore.doc('reportes/' + record_id).delete();
 }
}
```

entonces lo que quiero generar es un reporte en el reporte.ts

```
export class ReportePage implements OnInit {
  report:any;
  reportcategoria:string;
  reportdescripcion:string;


  // configuraciones para que pueda usar la camara
  capturedSnapURL:string;

  cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {

    quality: 100,    
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,    
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
  }

  constructor( private crudService:CrudService, private camera: Camera) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.crudService.read_report().subscribe(data => {

      this.report = data.map(e => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          isEdit: false,
          categoria: e.payload.doc.data()['categoria'],
          descripcion: e.payload.doc.data()['descripcion'],
          foto: e.payload.doc.data()['foto'],

        };
      })
      console.log(this.report);

    });
  }

  // metodo para tomar foto

  tomarFoto() {
    this.camera.getPicture(this.cameraOptions).then((imageData) => {
      // this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI gives file URI saved in local
      // this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL gives base64 URI

      let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.capturedSnapURL = base64Image;
    }, (err) => {

      console.log(err);
      // Handle error
    });
  }



  CreateRecord() {
    let record = {};
    record['categoria'] = this.reportcategoria;
    record['descripcion'] = this.reportdescripcion;
    record['foto'] =this.capturedSnapURL;


    this.crudService.create_report(record).then(resp => {
      this.reportcategoria = "";
      this.capturedSnapURL="";
      this.reportdescripcion = "";
      console.log(resp);
    })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

}
```

carga normal los datos de categoría y descripción pero en el caso de la imagen no lo hace alguna sugerencia para que logre cargar la imagen a firestore.¿ se puede cargar una imagen a firestore?

Comment: ¿Porqué **GRITAS**? ¿Sabes que en web escribir en mayúsculas se considera gritar? Por favor edita tu pregunta y escribe todo en minúsculas. Usa las mayúsculas y signos de puntuación adecuadamente. Saludos

Comment: gracias por la corrección

Comment: El título también, por favor :) gracias